# Put ui-sref in select / option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using AngularJS and I want to use ui-sref in option. This method that I use isn't working

```
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <select style="width: 117px;" ng-model="selectedTeam">
                    <option selected disabled>Teams</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="x in teams" value="{{x.team_id}}">
                        <a ui-sref="player-statistic.player-statistic-account({ teamId: x.team_id })">
                            {{x.team_name}}
                        </a>
                    </option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-show="selectedTeam">
            <select style="width: 117px;">
                    <option selected disabled>Account</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="y in account" ng-if="y.team_id == selectedTeam">
                            {{y.first_name}} {{y.last_name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
        </div>
```

Depending on which option you choose, this link opens by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tags` doesn't work inside select's `option` tag. You can do route navigation from controller function, by calling that function on `ng-change` of `select` box

```
<select style="width: 117px;" ng-model="selectedTeam" ng-change="changeLocation(selectedTeam)">
    <option selected disabled>Teams</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in teams" value="{{x.team_id}}">
      {{x.team_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changeLocation = function(teamId) {
  $state.go('player-statistic.player-statistic-account', {
    teamId: teamId
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi,instead x.team_id in changeLocation it's go ng-model. Thanks for help

Comment: @mrkibzk it would be one as the same thing, I updated the answer, thanks :)